# Guess the return type of function at runtime

Tags: c++, c, shared-objects

I was wondering if I can 'guess' the return type of a function at runtime.
To be more specific I use dlopen to load a dynamic library file, and then by calling dlsym I load a function (lets call it foo).
Function foo has been written and compiled from user (as a shared object) and can sometimes return double or either int.
So user for example can define foo as :

```
extern "C" {
int foo(int a){

    return a+2;
}
}
```

or:

```
extern "C" {
float foo(int a){

    return 1.0;
}
}
```

I have a compiled code which loads an .so file (the so file is compiled from the user). A snippet of the code is the following:

```
typedef int (*functionPointer)  (int ); //this sometimes is typedef int 
typedef float (*functionPointer)  (int ); //or typedef float
//can i "guess" the return type at runtime?
void *handle = dlopen(userLib.so, RTLD_LAZY);
functionPointer func = (functionPointer) dlsym(handle, "foo");
func(2);
```

And I want to know if this typedef can be guessed at runtime. The above snippet is allready compiled and "doesent" know what the function in  the given shared object will be.

Comment: Please spell check your posts.   This is hard to read.  Also, there are no types at runtime.   That information is gone.

Comment: No, this isn't possible.  You will have to give them different names.

Comment: @xaxxon done. Now I think it is readable

Comment: Just because there's no answer doesn't mean it's a bad question. This didn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: Perhaps you could have the user run another tool over their code to compile type information for the functions.

Comment: @JL2210: If I were to guess, I'd have to say that since there is an answer (No), and the fact that the answer is readily discernible from the [dlysm man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym), someone probably DV'd it for lack of research effort. But that's just a guess.

Comment: Interesting question but I don't think it's possible. Only think I can think of is returning some sort of indicator to know how to interpret the returned value  `indicator_t foo(void * retunr_val, int a)`. Maybe there are more clever ideas out there tho

Comment: Or maybe change the plugin ABI so it's expected to have `extern "C" std::variant<int, float> foo(int a)`

Comment: @DanielSchepler `extern "C"` and `std::variant<int, float>`: AFAIK, C++ types are not allowed with `extern "C"`. May be, a comparable C construct: `struct { enum { Int, Double } type; union { int i; double d; } value; }`

Comment: @Scheff Hmm, fair enough.  In that case, since `dlsym` and dynamic loading in general isn't portable anyway, it might make sense not to "abuse" `extern "C"` for this purpose especially when it doesn't fit the intended API, and instead use compiler-specific constructs to rename the function.  Or possibly even pass the mangled name to `dlsym` though that's pretty ugly.

Comment: Calling an external component without knowing what it does, is plain wrong. It might very well delete all your files or install a keylogger before you could find out if returns integer or float.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not possible in C as such information is not saved in the compiled executable. If you don't have access to the source code for the dynamic library, or at least the corresponding header files, you will have to disassemble and analyze it to figure out the return type.

One thing you can do is, for example, put together a list of known dynamic library hashes for which you know the return type is `int`. Then you can compute the hash of the library at the time of loading it, and cast the function pointer appropriately:

```
typedef int (*functionPointerInt)  (int ); 
typedef float (*functionPointerFloat)  (int ); 
_Bool returnTypeIsInt = so_hash_in_table("userLib.so");
void *handle = dlopen("userLib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
if(returnTypeIsInt)
{
    functionPointerInt func = (functionPointerInt) dlsym(handle, "foo");
    func(2);
}
else
{
    functionPointerFloat func = (functionPointerFloat) dlsym(handle, "foo");
    func(2);
}
```

Of course, this requires pre-analysis of the .so files.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if I can 'guess' the return type of a function at runtime.

No, you cannot. In fact, under some ABIs you may need to know the return type to safely call a function at all, as the return type is used to determine how much space to reserve on the stack for a return value.